# Updated IntelliJ to 2016.2.3 on OSX - keybinding issues # symbol alt+3 now just displays 3

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, keymapping

Previously on programmers.stackexchange.com but apparently off-topic for that forum.

I have found people complaining about the issue here: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/08/intellij-idea-2016-2-3-update-is-out/

I cannot ctrl+c or alt+3 so keybindings are messed.

Any ideas / temp fixes / resolutions before Jetbrains do a patch?

**Workaround from JetBrains:**

Masatoshi Iwasaki Kieran Simpson  Please, specify this jdk as a boot jdk https://bintray.com/jetbrains/intellij-jdk/download_file?file_path=jbsdk8u112b325_osx_x64.tar.gz

1. Download the archive
2. Unpack it
3. Run "Switch IDE boot JDK" action
4. Select "..." in the checkbox
5. Specify the unpacked directory in the file chooser
6. Reboot

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-160416#comment=27-1594109

Answer (score 0):

You can try [using the Standard JDK 1.8_102](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/switching-boot-jdk.html) I then had the terminal working again, but fonts were ugly.

Answer (score 0):

It is a general issue, I change my update channel to "Early Access Program"

I update to  IntelliJ 2016.2.4 (is the last RC) and them I change my channel again, be careful and don't update to  IntelliJ 2016.3 except you really want to.

You can do that going to the menu option "check updates" and click in the link updates in the middle of the text.

The close the popup and go to check updates again.

Remember change back your update channel.